# How i can break the item permission for a list item and assign all the Groups Read permission level

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, csom

I am working on a Remote Event Receiver, and i want to do the following:-

1. Break item permission + copy the permission.
2. For all the SharePoint groups assigned to a list item >> grant them Read permission level.

here is my code:-

```
foreach (ListItem i in collListItem)
                {
i.BreakRoleInheritance(true,false);
                            foreach (RoleAssignment r  in i.RoleAssignments)
                            {
```

but i am not sure how i can get all the security group associated with a list item + grant them Read permission? so i will make the item as Read-Only to all users?

Answer (score 1):

Even after breaking permission inheritance, you can't directly change a user's permissions to Read -- you technically have to remove their existing permissions, then Add the Read permission.

First, even though you only want to grant a single permission (i.e. `Read`), you still need to construct a [`RoleDefinitionBindingCollection`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee537039(v=office.15)) to hold that one RoleDefinition, because the [`RoleAssignmentCollection.Add`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server/ee544637(v=office.15)) only accepts a collection.

Then you have to loop through the existing `RoleAssignments` on the item to get a collection of users/groups (`Principals`) who already are assigned to the item.  If you are certain that all items already inherit from the parent, you could just do this once and get the collection of `Principals` before you being the loop, which would be more efficient, but could miss any users already assigned through broken inheritance.

Then, when you call `BreakRoleInheritance`, use the `false` parameter that wipes out the permissions on the item instead of copying the existing.  Then, finally you can loop through the collection of `Principals` you already have and create `Reader` Role Assignments for each `Principal` on the item.

```
RoleDefinition readerDef = ctx.Web.RoleDefinitions.GetByType(RoleType.Reader);
RoleDefinitionBindingCollection readOnlyBinding = new RoleDefinitionBindingCollection(clientContext);
readOnlyBinding.Add(readerDef);

foreach (ListItem i in collListItem)
{
    List<Principal> usersToGrantRead = new List<Principal>();

    foreach (RoleAssignment r  in i.RoleAssignments)
    {
        usersToGrantRead.Add(r.Member);
    }

    i.BreakRoleInheritance(false,false); // false clears out all permissions on the item
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();

    foreach (Principal p in usersToGrantRead)
    {
        i.RoleAssignments.Add(p, readOnlyBinding);
    }
    ctx.ExecuteQuery();
}
```

Comment: i tried your code, but i get this error `Cannot add a role assignment with empty role definition binding collection` on the last line `ctx.ExecuteQuery();`

Comment: Did you get the first three lines where the RoleDefinitionBinding is built before the loop?

Comment: yes of course ...

Comment: Actually, I thing the RoleAssignments actions take place instantly, try removing both `ExecuteQuery` references.